# Key Error Code when pulling data from a list in API project

Tags: python

I have a python project that pulls the UK gov api bank holidays, and I am trying to pull the list of bank holidays from a date range that covers 2024. I've been thrown an error key for the dates.

```
#import bank holidays from API data

import requests
from datetime import datetime


# retrieve the data of bank holidays
endpoint1 = 'https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json'
response = requests.get(endpoint1)
bank_holidays = response.json()
print (bank_holidays)

# use a data structure to show dates

start_date = datetime.strptime(bank_holidays['2024-01-01'],'%Y-%m-%d').date()
end_date = datetime.strptime(bank_holidays['2025-01-01'],'%Y-%m-%d').date()

#for date, holidays in bank_holidays.items():
holiday_date = datetime.strptime('date', '%Y-%m-%d').date()

for holidays in bank_holidays:
    if start_date <= holiday_date <= end_date:
      print(holiday_date['title '], 'is on', holiday_date['date'])

    else:
        print('Please try again')
```

the error code is:

```
"C:\Users\Natalie\Documents\project python\pythonProject\.venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\Natalie\Documents\project python\pythonProject\main.py"
Would you like to check the Bank Holiday/s this year? [Yes/No?] yes
Let's get started
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Natalie\Documents\project python\pythonProject\main.py", line 28, in <module>
    start_date = datetime.strptime(bank_holidays['2024-01-01'],'%Y-%m-%d').date()
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: '2024-01-01'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

My tutor has said I'm indexing on a value, not a key. But I can't work out what is missing.

Ideally I wanted to try to use slicing after pulling the total (should be 8 dates) but considering how lost I am I don't think it's possible lol.

```
date_range = pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', end='2025-01-01')
print (date_range[0:7])
```

Any ideas? I'm a total beginner and missed half my classes due to sickness, so I'm learning as I go atm.

Comment: Have you looked at `bank_holidays`? It's not a dictionary with dates as keys. The top-level keys are country names. Inside each of them is an `events` key, and this contains a list of events that have dates in the `date` key. What are you expecting `bank_holidays['2024-01-01']` to return?

Comment: `2024-01-01` appears in elements like `{"title": "New Year’s Day", "date": "2024-01-01", "notes": "", "bunting": true }`

Comment: your `for holidays in bank_holidays` loop never uses `holidays`.

Comment: you should be looping through `bank_holidays['england-and-wales']['events']`

Comment: when i print bank holidays, i get the top info ['england-and-wales']['events'] and then {"title": "New Year’s Day", "date": "2024-01-01", "notes": "", "bunting": true } I'm not sure how to include  bank_holidays['england-and-wales']['events'] in the loop

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of holidays for a particular country, use `bank_holidays[country]`. Within this, the holiday list is in the `events` dictionary key.

You don't need to refer to `bank_holidays` when parsing the dates `2024-01-01` and `2025-01-01`. Just pass those strings directly.

When testing a holiday in the list, you need to parse its `date` key.

WHen printing the information from the event list, use `holidays` as the dictionary, not `holiday_date`.

You had a typo in `holiday_date['title ']`. The space isn't in the key.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

country = 'england-and-wales'

# retrieve the data of bank holidays
endpoint1 = 'https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json'
response = requests.get(endpoint1)
bank_holidays = response.json()
eng_holidays = bank_holidays[country]['events']

start_date = datetime.strptime('2024-01-01','%Y-%m-%d').date()
end_date = datetime.strptime('2025-01-01','%Y-%m-%d').date()

holidays_found = False

for holidays in eng_holidays:
    holiday_date = datetime.strptime(holidays['date'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()

    if start_date <= holiday_date <= end_date:
        print(holidays['title'], 'is on', holidays['date'])
        holidays_found = True

if not holidays_found:
    print('Please try again')
```

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately I am still getting the error code for the dates '%Y-%m-%d', i think it is when it is passing through the 'events' 'country' section!

Comment: I tested my code before posting the answer, it works.

Comment: I'm not sure what was wrong with it on my side, I've had a few issues with pycharm since usage so maybe this

Answer (score 0):

The data you are getting from the request is a nested dictionary which is a data structure that uses key-value pairs to store data. This entails that you need to use a key to get the data from the dictionary. Perhaps your mentor meant this with his remark. For example, to retrieve everything for Scotland you use the key `scotland` in `bank_holidays['scotland']` to do so.

Sometimes it helps to print (parts of) a nested dictionary to understand how it is constructed.

```
for key in bank_holidays:
    print(f"Level 1 is : {key}")
    for sub in bank_holidays[key]:
        if sub == "events":
            print(f"\tLevel 2 is : {sub} {bank_holidays[key][sub][0]}")
        else:
            print(f"\tLevel 2 is : {sub}")
```

The code above will print out something similar to the block below. Here you can see that the three country names are the top level keys, I referred to them as `key` and that "division" and "events" are the sub level keys here named `sub`. Each bank holiday is represented as a dictionary with the keys: `title, date, notes, and bunting`.

```
Level 1 is : england-and-wales
    Level 2 is : division
    Level 2 is : events {'title': 'New Year’s Day', 'date': '2018-01-01', 'notes': '', 'bunting': True}
Level 1 is : scotland
    Level 2 is : division
    Level 2 is : events {'title': 'New Year’s Day', 'date': '2018-01-01', 'notes': '', 'bunting': True}
Level 1 is : northern-ireland
    Level 2 is : division
    Level 2 is : events {'title': 'New Year’s Day', 'date': '2018-01-01', 'notes': '', 'bunting': True}
```

Comment: thanks, this helps understand it. I'm still having the value error code but only on particular sections now, i think i need to print the %R somewhere to resolve, but cannot locate where to place in current code to run, this will like be the top of the sub sections, i don't have a string to run this through on list.

Comment: Can you show what the error message is? Perhaps I can help to solve it.

Comment: i've found a resolution now, i needed to remove 'data' from  this part of code - -- holiday_date = datetime.strptime(holidays['date'], '%Y-%m-%d').date() -- however, it only pulls dates for 2018-2025 instead of filtering. i think i just chose a very complicated AI project for a beginner.

Comment: @NatalieMcGreevy, don't fear that it is too complicated. Moving from error or not function code to the next error is part of learning.

Comment: is just incredibly frustrating - i feel like I'm nearly there but don't understand why it won't filter properly!

Comment: We've all been there. Your original code didn't filter because you were looping over the keys over the top level i.e. the country names.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the looping part of your code to this it will print out all the bank holidays for England:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

# retrieve the data of bank holidays
endpoint1 = 'https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json'
response = requests.get(endpoint1)
bank_holidays = response.json()

start_date = datetime.strptime('2024-01-01','%Y-%m-%d').date()
end_date = datetime.strptime('2025-01-01','%Y-%m-%d').date()

# loop over every holiday for England and Wales
for holiday in bank_holidays["england-and-wales"]["events"]:
    # extract only the value of the item
    # *_ takes in the notes and bunting which are not used
    title, date, *_ = holiday.values()
    holiday_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    # only print holidays in 2024
    if start_date <= holiday_date <= end_date:
        print(f"{title} is on {date}")
# if it doesn't work at all
else:
    print('Please try again')
```

Comment: thank you so much. the annotations really helped too. i had a feeling the issue was punting and event name and reading the debugger i saw i need to add something so it could run and then define. just got totally overwhelmed working out that step!

Comment: Glad to help. If you liked it, would you be so kind to accept the answer.

Comment: ive upvoted your answer but i need 15 points to make any other actions :)

Comment: Thank you, very much. Good luck on your path to learning to code!